# Bizarre login redirect to parallel instance after site migration

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, ce-1.9.2.2

We recently had our website migrated to a different hosting company. The host performed the migration for us, we just had to do something with DNS. After the day or two, it was all good it seemed. Then after having a new SSL Certificate installed, something bizarre began to occur.

On this computer that I am using now, I can log into Magento, make changes, submit products to eBay... all good on this end. However, if I or anyone else logs into Magento back-end on a different computer, it's as if they are logging into a residual instance of Magento that reflects the state of our website prior to the migration.

For example, the orders are not updated from recent sales, validation tokens are expired, and any changes made do not reflect on the website, nor can I see them in the back-end when logging in from this computer. The only place you can see the changes is on a different computer (except this one) logging into Magento admin.

It's got the Host company stumped, and I am no o

Answer (score 1):

We have recently migrated our system as well and I have experienced similar issue. There could be number of things depending how your system was migrated.

- Cache - clear all possible cache.
- cPanel - redirection based on the IP address.
- Host file - you may have setup hosts file on your machine which points straight to the new website.

To look into this issue further run CMD command:

```
tracert domainname.com
```

on your machine and other users. That could point you in the right direction.

Comment: Solution: One of those silly things. Ran tracert on domain > pointed towards old IP > checked local HOSTS file and found two line items. Deleted them, and now everyone is on the same page.